# Unable to connect to MongoDB from my Ubuntu VPS

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, digital-ocean, vps

I have an Ubuntu VPS hosted on DigitalOcean and a MongoDB Atlas.

The code connects fine when I connect from my desktop, but does not work on the VPS. I have added the VPS ip to the trusted list on Mongo control panel, but that has not worked. I also tried ufw allow 27017 but that hasn't worked either. How can I fix this?

I did my install of mongo exactly per instructions on the mongo website and started the service - it seems to work fine.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
import certifi

ca = certifi.where()

mongo_url = "mongodb+srv://admin:mypassword@cluster0.l2vfs.mongodb.net/Anagami_Data?retryWrites=true&w=majority"

try:
    client = MongoClient(mongo_url,tlsCAFile=ca)
    database = client["Anagami_Data"]
except Exception as e:
    print("internet is not connected")
```

Comment: what errors are you seeing ?  on what line ?
did you instal the same pymongo version on local machine and VPS ?

did you try to remove the games around certificate in the mongo_URL, and mongoclient to see if this has any effect ?

does the mongod.log  show you anything when you try to connect from the VPS ?

Comment: does your mongo port is open check with `netstat -tunpl` and bind address

Comment: thank you for the answers and suggestions @Dror . The problem turned out to be something quite stupid from my side - the try-catch block was shading out the error message that I did not have dnspython module installed - I discovered this only after removing the try catch. Thank you very much for your answers and suggestions! Sorry for the dumb question

Comment: @mohammad-naimi . Thank you very much for your answers and suggestions! The problem resolved itself - the try-catch block was blocking out the error on a missing dnspython module.